# Symfony 5 Twig 3 Webpack Encore fulllCalendar not rendered

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, twig, fullcalendar, webpack-encore

I'm using Symfony 5, Twig 3, Bootstrap, Webpack Encore and fullCalendar.

The calendar is not rendered into my template.

There is the code :

In the template :

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('fullcalendar_daygrid_css') }}
    <style>
        #calendar{

            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;

        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
  {{ 'advert.management.periods.title'|trans }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    ////
    <div id='calendar'></div>

    {% block javascripts %}
        {{ parent() }}
        <script>

            var events =  {{ events|raw }};

        </script>
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('periodsCreationfullCalendar') }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock body %}
```

In the called js :

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        
        plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        locale: 'fr',
        headerToolbar: {

          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth'

      },
      events: events,
      editable: true,
      eventResizableFromStart: true

    });
  
    calendar.render();

  });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Also, you target the calendar at an element called "calendar" (via `document.getElementById('calendar')`)...but in your code I don't see any element with that ID. e.g. I would be expecting to see `<div id="calendar"></div>` somewhere in the template.

Comment: Thanks for your hlep. I don't have any error and I have an div with id calendar : I edited the post.

Comment: Impossible to edit the post, but I have <div id='calendar'></div>

Comment: I edited it for you :-) . Check out the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) if you struggle to edit your posts.

Comment: Ok so we need to dive a bit deeper. For example, have you used the Javascript debugger to check if the `var calendar = new Calendar...` command and then the `calendar.render();` command is definitely being executed?

Comment: Yes, I did it with console.log(). This log is executed before and after calendar.render(), without error.

Comment: Ok. Then I'm sorry but it doesn't make sense why it isn't showing up. have you inspected the id="calendar" element with the browser's element inspector to check that a) it's definitely visible in the page (e.g. not hidden by some parent element's CSS, perhaps), and b) it gets populated with fullCalendar elements inside it?

Comment: Thank your very much for your help. The div is correctly displayed (with 'helllo' content by exemple), but the content isn't refresh with the calendar. In the source, after the complete load of the page, the div element don't contain the fullCalendar elements.

Comment: Using the debugger, can you check if `calendarEl` definitely points to the correct element in your page? It's very strange because this situation doesn't make a lot of sense. The code looks like it should work. (Admittedly I'm not a symfony/twig user, but I understand the concept of templates, and I can't see anything obviously wrong with yours.)

Comment: Apparently yes : <g id="calendar" transform="translate(4.000000, 4.000000)" fill="#322A1D" fill-rule="nonzero" class="fc fc-media-screen fc-direction-ltr fc-theme-standard">

Comment: The fact it has those classes added suggests that fullCalendar has acted on it and tried to create the calendar.

Comment: Looks like you are using `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('fullcalendar_daygrid_css') }}` instead of `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('fullcalendar_daygrid_css') }}`

Comment: Yes, exactly, it was a mistake. But, it wasn't the reason. Now, I 'm using the class name to get the calendar element in place of the id and all is right : var calendars = document.getElementsByClassName('calendar'); and var calendarEl = calendars[0];

Answer (score 1):

By using the class rather than the id, the problem is solved :

```
var calendars = document.getElementsByClassName('calendar');
var calendarEl = calendars[0];
```